# Is there an easy and effective way to see if a tkinter Text widget is full?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program that gets some some text from a `website` (link) then outputs it into a `Text` widget.

But I want a way to check if the text exceeds the `Text` widget so then I can call my `clear_Text_Box()` function.

Is there any way to do this?

I searched up things like: *tkinter how to know if my TEXT box is full*, or *tkinter Text box methods*, but it gives me unrelated things such as *how to create full screen window in tkinter* and so on.

My `Text` widget is `(width = 30,height = 70)`.

My `clear_Text_Box()` function:

```
def clear_Text_Box(Text_Box): # I have this function, so it clears the Text box if text
                              # exceeds the Text box.
    Text_Box.config(state = 'normal')
    Text_Box.delete('0.0','end')
    Text_Box.config(state = 'disabled')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "full"?  A Text widget is scrollable, it can hold however much text you want.  If you just want to limit how big it gets, you could do something like `Text_Box.delete('0.0','end - 100 lines')` every time you insert data, to limit it to 100 lines.

Comment: Full meaning that it goes off the Text widget without scrolling.

Comment: You can tell if the Text has enough content to need scrolling by comparing `Text_Box.yview()` to `(0.0, 1.0)`.

Comment: Thanks, 1 last thing, how do you compare them? Do you just do something like : `if Text_Box.yview> (0.0,1)` or what?

Comment: Just compare for equality.  That specific value will only be returned by `.yview()` if the entire contents of the Text is visible.

Comment: Can I just do `if Text_Box.y_view() == ('0.0','1'):  ... else: clear_Text_Box(Text_Box)` ?

Comment: Right, except that you don't want those quote marks - the returned value is numeric.

Comment: Oh so it’s just 0.0,1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing if it's *full* can be a bit tricky at the very edge (ie: knowing if it's possible to squeeze in one more space or "i" character", but knowing whether or not some text has scrolled out of view is easy.

You can call the `yview` and `xview` methods of the widget each will return a tuple of two fractions: the amount above (or to the left) the viewable region and the amount below (or to the right). From the official documentation for the `yview` method:

> The first element gives the position of the first visible pixel of the first character (or image, etc) in the top line in the window, relative to the text as a whole (0.5 means it is halfway through the text, for example). The second element gives the position of the first pixel just after the last visible one in the bottom line of the window, relative to the text as a whole.

So, if you call `yview` and `xview` and they return `(0.0, 1.0)` then everything in the widget is visible.

```
if Text_Box.xview() == (0.0, 1.0) and Text_Box.yview() == (0.0, 1.0):
    # all text is visible
    ...
```